# Is it possible to edit or make layers selectable using data from ArcGIS online?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-online

I am new to using data from ArcGIS online. I am trying to run some analyses using data I obtained from ArcGIS online, specifically the EPA - Ecoregions file of North America listed below. (Note: I have ArcGIS 10.1):

[EPA Ecoregions](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=69e678375433435eabf537cc020e03a6)

I cannot edit, select or run tools on the data. The data is listed as "Not Selectable" in the Table of Contents tab.

[image: screenshot]

When using the Set Selectable Layers command, it doesn't appear and, thus, can't change it.

Is it possible to change this setting so I can run analyses using this layer from ArcGIS online? Or is it possible to save this data as a shapefile? Data -> Export Data is not available when right-clicking.

(Note: Access and Use of Contents is listed as NONE on the website, so I believe it's usable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this data was shared strictly as a webmap. However, you can access this data directly from the EPA website here:

https://www.epa.gov/eco-research/ecoregions-north-america

Comment: Thanks for the help. I still wonder if there is a solution to other datasets as this isn't the only one I've had this problem. I guess when it's strictly as a webmap, you cannot select and edit the data?

Comment: @Phil - see my answer for your options with web maps.

Answer (score 0):

For web maps in general, if they are in a WMS (web map service), you can't do anything but display them.  However, if they are in a WFS (web feature service), you'll be able to alter the symbology, export the data, and analyse it.

For ArcGIS online, some features are available for export.  To export them, they must be extractable.  Export extractable features using the 'Extract Data' tool.  There is extensive documentation here and a detailed explanation of extractable data: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/use-maps/extract-data.htm